# Code to display capital of country and continent with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to stackoverflow. I have written a code in html with javascript in it. The code displays a textbox in html and by typing names of countries, it helps us to find the capital of the country and its continent. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black" onload="document.getElementById('myedit').value=''">
<font color="white" size="4"><b>Please type the country name to find its capital and continent</b></font>
<br>
<input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" id="myedit" onchange="editChange()" onkeyup="editChange()" />
<div id="result">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// country,capital,continent
var cName = new Array();
cName[0] = 'Germany,Berlin,Europe';
cName[1] = 'United States of America,Washington DC,North America';
cName[2] = 'India,New Delhi,Asia';
cName[3] = 'United Kingdom,London,Europe';
function editChange() {
obj = document.getElementById('myedit');
s = obj.value.toLowerCase();
res = '';
for (i=0; i<cName.length; i++) {
s2 = cName[i].toLowerCase().substr(0, s.length);
if (s2 == s && s != '') {
sp = cName[i].split(',');
res += '<table><tr><td><font color="white" size="5">'+sp[0]+', '+sp[2]+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+sp[1]+'<font></td></tr></table>';
}
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res == '' ? '<font color="white" size="5"><i>&nbsp; Not found</i></font>' : res;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, if we type "u" in the textbox, it shows all the countries starting with "U" and as we go on typing the first few characters of the country name we get more specific countries. But in case of "United States of America" and other countries where there are two or more words in the name of the country, the above code does not work if we type only "states". Is there some way out with the above code with which we get the result "United States of America" by either typing "uni..." or "st..."?
Thank you

Comment: Why you don't use from jQuery plugins like [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: @RasoolGhafari - OP wants to learn the nuts and bolts. Hi MKT welcome to SO.  Never use the `<font>` tag :) it's deprecated (being phased out).

Comment: you can do this using jquery autocomplete , why to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Guy wants to learn *how*, come on.

Comment: Its important to do task like this. Otherwise what happens when you need to create a custom and all you know is jQuery. Keep practicing its how you become a expert.

Comment: Exactly - if you just use other people's wheels, when yours breaks, you're up the creek.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use indexOf then you will find the word in any position instead of just the beginning.

```
if(cName[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(s) != -1){
//your code
}
```

this would be replacing

```
s2 = cName[i].toLowerCase().substr(0, s.length);
if (s2 == s && s != '') {
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This works. But when I remove whatever I had written, it shows the entire list. Instead, wouldn't it be better if it shows nothing whenever we remove all the text from the textbox, just as it looks like when the page is loaded for the first time. Thanks again.

Comment: Like this? `if (s && cName[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(s) != -1) {` (see above).

Comment: @Thomas nice one. +1 for ease of use and not pulling out regex especially considering closing quote in my answer :)

Comment: Just noticed one thing. It is searching for everything. Not just country name but for the continent as well as capital. Can we restrict the search to the text in the first part? I mean only the country names which are listed in the first part of the array. for eg: cName[1] = 'United States of America,Washington DC,North America';

Comment: For that you could `.split()` like in your original post, maybe use `.substr()` but it would be ugly, or use a regex with the `\w` (word boundary) option - I know I keep plugging regex but they're the future, man, and they're here now.  Whoa.

Comment: I do agree regex is likely the best route. The only problem it is pretty hard to get hold of in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `RegExp`.  Here's a rewrite and a cleanup with a few tips commented in.

```
<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>

<b>Please type the country name to find its capital and continent</b>
<br>
<input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" id="myedit" />
<div id="result">&nbsp;</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var cName = new Array();
cName[0] = 'Germany,Berlin,Europe';
cName[1] = 'United States of America,Washington DC,North America';
cName[2] = 'India,New Delhi,Asia';
cName[3] = 'United Kingdom,London,Europe';

function editChange() {
    // THIS keyword will usually be the object you're looking for 
    // (but careful, it's "powerful", see what I wrote later).
    var str = this.value.toLowerCase();

    // Make a new regex from the search string.
    var regex = new RegExp(str);

    // Store all results in an array so they're easy to work with later.
    var res = [];

    // Cache length so JS doesn't have to recalculate each time.
    var len = cName.length;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Here's the trick - cName will look to see
        // if anything from inside the regex matches.
        // For example, /sta/ will be found in "united states"
        if (cName[i].toLowerCase().match(regex)) {
            res.push(cName[i]);
        }
    }

    // No need to make a new table for every entry...right?
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res.join("<br>");
}

// Try to separate functionality from markup. Leave your HTML clean
// and put JS stuff in JS.  :)
document.getElementById('myedit').onkeyup = editChange;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Regex is a powerful topic.  When coders say "powerful" they usually mean complex and headache-causing, but with amazing capabilities.

Regex is that, and it's fun and helpful once you get the hang of it.  It's a great way to solve your question.

I leave you with a [popular quote](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Hey Steve! Thanks for all the suggestions you have given. I will definitely try to implement them whenever I code for the next time. One more thing. Just read my comment on Thomas's answer. Hope you can add something to it. Thanks

Comment: @MKT - that's easy: `if (s && cName[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(s) != -1) {`  Thanks for the feedback.  I'd appreciate an upvote but his is a better answer IMO, more elegant. Anyway, please remember to mark an answer as "solved" once you're in the clear.  Fun question BTW.

Comment: Tried to vote up both the answers. But it seems I need some more reputation before I can vote any answer up.